# Acoustic Communication issues

Tags: receiver, rf-power, electronics, transmitter, grounding

[![I've attached schematic, I am connecting transducer directly to that header pins on receiver side. On transmitter side I am connecting op-Amp to boost voltage to +10v -10v.][1]][1]I am working on Acoustic underwater communication system at 60 kHz. I am using Op-Amp on transmitter side which amplifies signal to -10v to +10v. I observed a weird thing about this system that it only works when it is grounded to my home's common ground. For example if I supply power through separate battery it wont work. But if I supply it through adapter on both transmitter and receiver side it works fine with reasonable range. Anyone has any idea why it behaves like this and how to fix it? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Posting a schematic would help us understand your problem.

Comment: One possibility: because the whole thing doesn't work as designed (at least in the environment you're testing it in) but it *can* sneak a signal through the power wiring.

Comment: Hi I've attached  schematics, let me know if you have any solution in mind. Thanks a lot

Comment: The schematic image is missing. It looks like you may have added an image, but deleted the actual URL from the text so it doesn't exist. Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely answer without measurements or schematics is that you transponders are connected to earth by the coupling Capacitance of water , while the common mode of a floating battery to an unbalanced electronic circuit has more antenna effects pickup up one side of the battery terminal circuit (0V gnd plane) than the other from high E-field line signals.

Thus shunting the battery to PE earth reduces these ambient line CM signals.  Also using a cap should work as well.

An alternative solution could be to use  a CM choke or 1:1 audio transformer with good accurate 1:1 ratios to act as  BALUN or CM choke to convert UNbalanced circuit into a BALanced circuit.

### Rev A

Although the circuit is not posted yet , an audio transformer just isolates this from ground making unbalanced inputs sensitive to common mode line noise interference. A CAP or earth ground is necessary to shunt the CM interference or a BALUN transformer in series to balance the interface and attenuate the common mode noise.

Comment: Hello Tony! Although IMHO the OQ is OT, we look forward to seeing more answers from you here. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am using audio transformer, I've just put schematics in my question. I'm considering to add bandpass filter on receiver side. Probably it might fix the issue. I'm not sure though.